# Improve "Insert Hyperlink" Dialog

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, editor

Today I have discovered the "Insert Hyperlink" dialog the first time somehow. [And it has confused me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368272/optional-title-in-creating-hyperlink-does-not-work).

Personaly, this is not a problem, since I don't use this dialog anyway. However I am sure, a big quantity of new users, who are also new to markdown, use it. If it can confuse me, I am sure it can confuse new users.

Can we redesign the dialog to something like that:

[image: New Hyperlink Dialog Example]

This way, it is more explicit.

Following the H&I Queue, I have seen many Hyperlinks incorrectly formatted. So I think this could adress the problems in some part.

Comment: I actually think yours is more confusing and way too wordy.

Comment: See my own question recently at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368271/https-by-default-when-creating-a-link : please use `https://`  as default, not `http://`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah, you got an upvote. Actually your question was the reason I discovered this dialog ;)